# Typecast Map<String, String> to Map<Object, Object>

Tags: java, generics

```
Map<String, String> fieldAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();

fieldAttributes.put("a", "48");
fieldAttributes.put("b", "");
fieldAttributes.put("c", "4224");
```

Now I need to cast `Map<String, String>` to `Map<Object, Object>`

How can I do this. I tried `? extends Object` but not sure how to use it.

Comment: you can directly use Map<Object, Object> right ???

Comment: Why Map<Object,Object>? after all **String** is **Object**

Comment: @AVD because i need to feed  the object to a function which will take it as  Map<Object,Object> only.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?  `Map<Object,Object>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `Map<String,String>`.  Try `Map<?,?>` instead - it's a supertype of both `Map<String,String>` and `Map<Object,Object>`, so it might be what you want.  Is the function that requires `Map<Object,Object>` something you can change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
Map<Object, Object> properties = (Map) fieldAttributes;
```

The compiler gives you an appropriate warning, but it compiles.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. A `Map<String, String>` is not a `Map<Object, Object>`. If it was, you could do

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<Object, Object> map2 = (Map<Object, Object>) map;
map2.put(Integer.valueOf(2), new Object());
```

which would break the type safety that generics bring.

So, you'll indeed have to use a raw map, or use a `Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> genMap = fieldAttributes;
```

OR

```
Map<Object, Object> gMap = (Map)fieldAttributes;
```

Comment: Or just `Map<?,?>`.  The "extends Object" is kind of implied.

Comment: Yes, Map<?, ?> can be used as every class extends Object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting, you can just use `Object` instead of `String`:

```
Map<Object, Object> fieldAttributes = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
fieldAttributes.put("a", "48");
fieldAttributes.put("b", "");
fieldAttributes.put("c", "4224");
```

When iterating the `Map`, you can use `Object`'s `.toString()` method to transform.